# Checking if entities match an id in on relation where it could show up in either of two columns

Tags: postgresql, join, select

### The problem

I'm trying to make a page for a website (with PostgreSQL database) that allows the owner of a group to add new members from their friends list.

Given the `owner_id` of a `Group` its `group_id` I need to retrieve only the `user_id`s from users who are both friends with the owner, and not in the group.

### The relations being queried

I need to use the following relations

- `UserFriend`: Stores two `user_id`s to connect those two users from the `User` relation to each other as friend.
- `UserGroup`: Stores a `user_id` and `group_id` to connect the `Group` relation to its members in the `User` relation.

The two relations are described as follows:

**UserFriend**

```
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 user_id_a | integer |           | not null | 
 user_id_b | integer |           | not null |
```

**UserGroup**

```
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 user_id  | integer |           | not null | 
 group_id | integer |           | not null |
```

### My attempt so far with example data

For example, given the data below, I want to find all users that are friend with user 3, and not in group 3.

```
SELECT user_id_a, user_id_b FROM UserGroup UG, UserFriend UF 
    WHERE (UF.user_id_a = 3 AND UF.user_id_b != UG.user_id)
       OR (UF.user_id_b = 3 AND UF.user_id_a != UG.user_id)
       AND UG.group_id = 3 GROUP BY user_id_a, user_id_b;
```

**Expected Result**

```
 user_id_a | user_id_b 
-----------+-----------
         1 |         3
```

*Even better if it could just show something like*

```
 possible_members 
------------------
                3
```

**Actual Result**

```
 user_id_a | user_id_b 
-----------+-----------
         1 |         3
         3 |         2
         3 |         4
```

#### Example data

**UserFriend**

```
 user_id_a | user_id_b 
-----------+-----------
         1 |         2
         1 |         3
         1 |         4
         3 |         4
         3 |         2
```

**UserGroup**

```
 user_id | group_id 
---------+----------
       1 |        1
       2 |        1
       3 |        1
       4 |        1
       1 |        2
       2 |        3
       3 |        3
       4 |        3
```

### Analysis

I'm fairly certain that the issue has something to do with the way I'm handling the fact that the `user_id` I'm trying to match could be in either column of `UserFriend`, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've also tried using `JOIN`s without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use set operations. If the user is 42, and the group is 1001, that would be

```
(SELECT user_id_a FROM userfriend
 WHERE user_id_b = 42
    UNION
 SELECT user_id_b FROM userfriend
 WHERE user_id_a = 42
)
   EXCEPT
SELECT user_id FROM usergroup
WHERE group_id = 1001;
```

`UNION` creates a result set that is the union of two query results and removes duplicate rows. `EXCEPT` returns all result rows from the left side that do *not* occur on the right side.